# Lift measure for a frequent itemset

Tags: r, data-mining

I found it's possible to add the lift measure to the quality measures of a frequent itemset in R returned by the Eclat algorithm:

```
frequentItems <- eclat(trans, parameter = list(supp = support, maxlen = 15))

quality(frequentItems)$lift <- interestMeasure(frequentItems,
                                               measure="lift", trans = trans)
```

I can't understand how the lift measure is calculated since I know it's related to association rules (antecedent ==> consequent) and not to a frequent itemset.